# How to change build directory and not getting that replaced by _next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wanted to change my build directory from ".next" to "customFolder".

In next.config.js , i did

```
distDir:'customFolder',
```

now  my build is going to that folder by my url still looks like "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/components_Layout_js.js?ts=1687266907032", i want to change the path to http://localhost:3000/customFolder/static/chunks/components_Layout_js.js?ts=1687266907032 as well

tried :-

```
`distDir:'customFolder',`
```

also tried

```
` webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
   config.output.publicPath = '/myproject/_next/';
    config.output.chunkFilename = 'chunks/[name].js';

    return config;
  },`
```